# Nested bindings with multiple view models

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Please help me in resolving this issue.I am stuck on this issue from last 3 weeks.
    I have 1 html file whose parent div id is binded to knockout observable by creating object of 1 javascript. Inside parent div id of html, there is another child div id which i need to bind with second javascript object and populate the foreach block.But i am unable to implement this scenario.I'll be really veryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy greatful if someone help me in resolving this scenario.

```
I have mentioned here some dummy example of my scenario.Please ignore minor errors of naming convention and trailing quotes as its just a dummy code.
```

## HTML FILE

(div id "main" is binded to MainModel.js . On object of MainModel.js , showCateogaries() method is called and from this method getCategories1() is called which is populating the value of categories .But actually this is not getting populated and error is coming "unable to parse bindings" )

```
<div  id="main" data-bind="visible: showMain">
        <div  id="subMain" >
              <p data-bind="text: name"></p>
              <ul id="tabArea"  data-bind="foreach : categories">
                       <li  data-bind="text: $data.categoryname ></li>
              </ul>
                </div>      
</div>
```

## Demo.js

```
var main1=new MainModel(); //Main View Model
ko.applyBindings(main1,$('#main')[0]);

main1.showCateogaries();
```

## MainModel.js

```
function(ko,subMainModel){
     var  mainModel =function(){
           this.showCategories = function(){
            subMainModel.getCategories1();              
        }
     }
}
```

## subMainModel.js

```
function(ko){

     this.categories = ko.observableArray([]);

      this.getCategories1 = function(){
                // some code goes here
        this.categories(categoryArray.reverse());   
      };
}
```

Comment: <li  data-bind="text: $data.categoryname ></li> missing trailing quote

Comment: showMain is not declared on mainModel?

Comment: MainModel (capital M) is not declared anywere in your code?

Comment: @Anders :Its a dummy code so i have not mentioned all details.          this.showMain = ko.observable(false); is mentioned in MainModel.js Trailing quotes are present and naming convention is also followed properly

Comment: This code is working properly if i mention this.categories = ko.observableArray([]); and getCategories1() inside mainModel.js . But as i want them in separate js then problem is coming